# Autorun standalone script from USB on mount

Tags: linux, usb, autorun

I am trying to auto start a shell script when the USB drive is mounted. Every post I have seen about this has answers that are dependant on doing something on the computer such as creating a service. I need something that will execute directly from the USB drive without needing to use the computer for anything. Is something like this possible that is executed on mounting the dive?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1648939